# Fast way to forward an Outlook email as a zip

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, automation, compression, zip

I need to find a quick way to select an email in Outlook 2010 and forward the email as a zip attachment.  The recipient will always be the same.  The subject and body of the email will always be the same (blank).

How do I do this?

EDITS: The reason I'm doing this is because I am sending false-negative spam emails to my spam filtering service.  They require the email to be zipped to preserve email headers that would otherwise be lost if I just hit "forward."  The reason I want to automate this is because it is something I have to do many times a week.

Comment: Why would you want or need to do this? Why don't you just forward the email as is? You're going to zip the original email message and forward it in another email message? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perform a Drag and Drop operation into the choosen directory and use the program of your choice to create an archive.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I have added the purpose above as an edit.

Comment: @Ramhound - I am currently doing this with dragging and WinZip.  Is there a faster way?  I have to do this many times a week.

Comment: @anon - Its a three step process.  That includes attaching the file and hitting the send button.

Comment: You can do it with VBA.

Comment: @techie007 - Great!  If you post your code below, I can try it out and accept it as an answer.

Comment: @anon As we're not a script writing service, I was just making a suggestion for you/others to research. If you take a crack at it, and run into a problem while implementing, common back with those specific questions. BTW, If you use "Forward As Attachment", instead of just "Forward", the whole message will be sent as an attachment and the headers will be preserved, no need to zip the message.